# Linq select all NOT found linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
class Module
{
    long MID    // PK
    string Name
}

class ModuleBlock
{
    long MID      // FK
    long BID      // FK
}

class Block
{
    long BID      // PK
    string Info
}
```

I want to select all the Blocks that do NOT have a BID in ModuleBlocks.

How do I do this query?

I'm pretty sure it's something along the lines of join Blocks with ModuleBlocks on BID and check the nulls but how do I do this in LINQ?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-entities/Linq-to-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the 'nulls' since you do not give any nullable properties in your pseudo-code. But the LINQ query would/could be something like this I think:

```
List<Module> modules = ...
List<ModuleBlock> moduleBlocks = ...
List<Block> blocks = ...

var blocksWithNoBidsInModuleBlocks = blocks
   .Where(b => !moduleBlocks.Select(mb => mb.BID).Contains(b.BID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to do this client-side rather than translating it into SQL, you could modify [MoreLinq's `ExceptBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs) method to work on sequences of two different types.

Then you can call

```
var modulelessBlocks =
 allBlocks.Except(
     allModuleBlocks,
     block => block.MID,
     moduleblock => moduleblock.MID);
```

This has the advantage of only iterating each source once.

Here's an example of the modified iterator - you'd have to modify the other methods to match:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptByImpl<TSource, TSecond, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelectorSource,
    Func<TSecond, TKey> keySelectorSecond,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>(
        second.Select(keySelectorSecond),
        keyComparer);
    foreach (var element in first)
    {
        TKey key = keySelectorSource(element);
        if (keys.Contains(key))
        {
            continue;
        }
        yield return element;
        keys.Add(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly easy way to do it using only joins:

```
var bids =
    from m in modules
    join mb in moduleBlocks on m.MID equals mb.MID
    select mb.BID;

var bs =
    from b in blocks
    join bid in bids on b.BID equals bid into gbids
    where !gbids.Any()
    select b;
```

The second query gives you the result you want.